# L'emploi métonymique « être positif » peut-il avoir un complément et quel serait-il ?

Tags: anglais, prépositions, formulation, compléments, transitivité

La BDL parle de l'emprunt syntaxique à l'anglais « [tester positif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3671) » (*to test positive, to be tested positive…* ; et avec *contrôler* ; on pourrait ajouter *se faire tester pour*) et pour elle ce qui explique l'emploi de plus en plus fréquent c'était l'importance grandissante des tests antidopages dans le domaine du sport par le truchement des journalistes sportifs :

> [...] En effet, on dit plutôt en français qu’un test ou un contrôle
> est positif, c’est-à-dire qu’il révèle la présence d’une bactérie,
> d’un virus ou d’une substance donnée; par **métonymie**, on dira même
> qu’une personne est positive, lorsque le contexte ne prête à aucune
> équivoque, pour exprimer que son organisme présente une réaction
> positive à un examen donné. Mais on ne saurait parler d’une personne
> qui « teste positif ». Les calques de la syntaxe anglaise peuvent être
> remplacés par des formulations telles que *contrôle de dopage
> positif*, *test positif*, *résultat du test positif* ou, **en parlant
> de la personne qui subit le test, *obtenir un résultat positif*, *être
> déclaré positif*, *être positif***.
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique, OQLF, « [tester positif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3671) »,
> 2021, je souligne ]

Quoiqu'il en soit, ça me semble en usage depuis longtemps (au Québec, dans mon lexique) et même si *obtenir un résultat X à un test de dépistage du X* me vient facilement en tête, je ne suis pas particulièrement familier avec l'emploi métonymique sans le calque... Et je me demande si ça se transpose au contexte sanitaire.

---

Peut-on confirmer qu'on peut ajouter un complément à ces formulations (en particulier « être positif » conjugué), par exemple « à la maladie/au virus/au produit X » ou autrement ; a-t-on plutôt besoin d'« [être atteint](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_atteint/6215) » pour l'avoir en contexte sanitaire plutôt que de dopage ; est-ce bien la préposition *à* qui est employée le cas échéant ?

Comment: Le sujet me fait penser à un sketch de Gérard Dupontel où le personnage vient de passer un test HIV et dit quelque chose comme: *C'est bon, ouf ! Tout est positif.*

Comment: Mais oui, le Québec a beaucoup de structures axées sur l'anglais. En voilà une.

Answer (score 1):

La présence d'un complément de l'adjectif à ce sens technique de "positif" est loins d'être nouvelle. [Voici un exemple de 1972](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nlQnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22test+positif+%C3%A0%22&dq=%22test+positif+%C3%A0%22) dans les *Archives de l'institut Pasteur de Tunis*.

L'usage semble clairement en faveur de *à* pour introduire ce complément (dans une proportion d'environ 4-pour-1 sur le site de *La Presse*, par exemple). On rencontre un peu de variation avec *pour* que j'attribue surtout à l'influence ou une traduction trop proche de l'anglais (*[testing] positive for X*).